# How to define MapStore for Helm based Hazelcast Deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, hazelcast

How to define MapStore for Helm based Hazelcast Deployment

We are using Hazelcast Server with Helm based Deployment in K8S. How to define the MapStore configuration for this case.

1. MapStore java implementation should be in Server or Client.
2. I am not able to find any sample how to configure MapStore in Helm.
3. My goal is to use write back to DB in hazelcast. I am able to get this working with Embedded Hazelcast or using Hazelcast Service, but not sure know does it work in case of Helm based Deployment in K8S

Answer (score 0):

You can use MapStore (or MapLoader) in the Helm-based deployment, but it's not a "one-click" operation.

You need to perform the following steps:

1. Implement your MapStore class and copy it into a volume available in your Kubernetes environment
2. Specify the [customVolume](https://github.com/hazelcast/charts/blob/master/stable/hazelcast/values.yaml#L209) parameter in your `values.yaml` (will be mounted into your container as `/data/custom/`)
3. Configure your MapStore in [your Hazelcast configuration](https://github.com/hazelcast/charts/blob/master/stable/hazelcast/values.yaml#L37)

Comment: Thanks let me try it out.
1. I assume it would be a build by MapStore class as a Jar. 
2. In customVolume parameter - I have to provide the jar name.